# .NET Core Identity - get current login provider

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

For example, I logged in via "Google", then user can go to some page and click "Send Email" if user was logged in via Google I want to send email with using Gmail.

How can I differ what login provider did user use to log in? For example Built-In or Google or Microsoft

Comment: I am not able to test this at the moment myself, but based on this previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478047/how-to-get-the-current-external-provider-in-homecontroller-of-asp-net-core-2-0-m), you should be able to query the AuthenticationMethod claim to check the identity provider.

Comment: Great! It helped, thanks.